# Tomcat is not loading on browser after deploying geoserver WAR - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, localhost, geoserver

I installed tomcat 8 on my ubuntu 18.04 system. Later I have downloaded geoserver web archive from geoserver page and deployed the war file on /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps. Tomcat is working fine before deploying the war file.[ localhost:8080] is working fine. But the problem I am getting is after deploying the geoserver war in webapps directory tomcat is not loading on browser.

I have started and restarted tomcat server many times using the command sudo service tomcat8 start and sudo service tomca8 restart. But it's not working after deploying war file.

I would like to install geoserver on tomcat server. I would like to load the geoserver web page as localhost:8080/geoserver.

Any help will be appreciated.

After checking the log file I found these error.

```
16-Aug-2019 21:31:30.011 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextDestroyed Unregistering JAI factory class com.sun.media.jai.opimage.ColorConvertCRIF
16-Aug-2019 21:31:30.012 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextDestroyed Unregistering JAI factory class com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MlibXorRIF
16-Aug-2019 21:31:30.012 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextDestroyed Unregistering JAI factory class com.sun.media.jai.opimage.XorCRIF
16-Aug-2019 21:31:30.013 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextDestroyed Unregistering JAI factory class com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MlibAbsoluteRIF
16-Aug-2019 21:31:30.013 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextDestroyed Unregistering JAI factory class com.sun.media.jai.opimage.AbsoluteCRIF
```

Comment: There should be Tomcat log files.  I'm not positive where they would be but my guess is `/var/log/tomcat8`.  The files should help direct you to what is wrong.

Comment: those are not errors, look further down the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred due to some permission issues.
    sudo chown -R user:user /var/lib/tomcat8.

In order to deploy any web apps on tomcat8 the tomcat itself should be the owner. By changing the directory permission to tomcat itself it worked!.